# How to route a single an ip to a localhost?

Tags: windows-7, localhost, routing

I have a web server on my localhost on win-7,

and I want to route my local network ip: (192.168.1.120) to the localhost,

so that if I type `http://192.168.1.120/` in my browser it would directly connect to the localhost, as if I typed `http://127.0.0.1/`

I tried to do it like this, in different variations:

```
route ADD 192.168.1.120 MASK 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1
```

But it never worked of course...

Does anyone know the correct method?

Comment: Would you not be better trying to get your webserver to listen on your local ip address rather than just listening on localhost?

Comment: I did set my webserver to listen on `192.168.1.120` - but it still takes me long time to connect for some reason. But if I open my site as `http://127.0.0.1` which is actually the same machine, it loads up in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

if you do a tracert of both the local IP address and localhost, you will see that there is only 1 hop, the machine itself.

So there is no need to do any routing.

Perhaps you arent explaining your question very well?

Comment: Well I've an apache web server on a local machine. And if I open my site as `http://127.0.0.1/` it absolutely consistently opens it up in the very instant moment I hit the the enter. But if I type  `http://192.168.1.120/` which is my network address, or otherwise refresh some of the pages using that address, it waits for the browser to connect for some significant amount of time. If I do consequent requests though, eg immediately refreshing the page after first loading, it would then open quickly, but if I refresh after a minute or less it then gets me another 10 secs of waiting...

Comment: It sounds like your webserver isnt configured properly.

Comment: It's a fresh install, but well, here is the config, which may reveal: http://pastebin.com/V0Z0qhJX